# What is the difference between appsettings.json and runtimeconfig.json?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

What is purpose of either of that files?

When to use appsettings.json?

When to use runtimeconfig.json?

Answer (score 2):

`appsettings.json` is for configuring your application. You (or your IDE) create this file. You manually maintain it with changes that you need.

`runtimeconfig.json` is an internal configuration for the .NET runtime, used when it needs to run your application. Generally, you don't touch, edit, maintain or even version control this file. It's created automatically when your application is built.

It's never an either/or situation: you generally use both. `appsettings.json` is used explicitly/manually, while `runtimeconfig.json` is generally used under the hood and very rarely used manually.

Comment: This docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/ states that runtimeconfig.json can be used to configure the behavior of .NET *applications* at run time. Moreover, runtimeconfig.template.json can be created, and all configuration will be put to runtimeconfig.json. So theoretically I can forget about appsettings.json and put in all configurations to runtimeconfig.template.json. Why there is that possibility (I'm about runtimeconfig.template.json), if there is appsettings.json?

Answer (score 0):

The appsettings. json file is an application configuration file used to store configuration settings such as database connections strings etc. This is basically a configuration file for configuring your application. You can able to edit it manually, whenever the changes are required.

The runtimeconfig. json file is generated automatically in the output directory when the application is built . It is basically a internal configuration for the .Net Runtime. There is no need of making any changes or any edit in this file manually as it is automatically generated at your application's Runtime.